# Títulos de las preguntas que integran mensajes en ingles u otros idiomas

Tags: discusión, preguntas, títulos-de-preguntas

Fijándome en algunas preguntas, estas tienen el comienzo del titulo en ingles ya sea el mensaje del compilador u otro tipo de mensaje, como las que se muestran de ejemplo a continuación:

**Pregunta n1:**

1. “splice() offset past end of array” en diferentes versiones de Perl

**Pregunta n2:**

2. “Unknown provider: uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider” al probar con Jasmine código que usa el componente de Google Maps para AngularJS

Pienso que sería más cómodo incluir el tipo de mensaje en ingles en medio del titulo o al final de este pues, creo que es más fácil de leer y mucho más si no se sabe algo de ingles, teniendo que saltar hasta la parte en español para después volver a leer el mensaje en ingles y así entender de que se trata, algunos posibles ejemplos, sobre los anteriores.

**Sobre la primera:**

1. En diferentes versiones de Perl obtengo > “splice() offset past end of array”
2. En diferentes versiones de Perl > “splice() offset past end of array”
3. En diferentes versiones de Perl “splice() offset past end of array”

**Sobre la segunda:**

2. Al probar con Jasmine código que usa el componente de Google Maps para AngularJS recibo > “Unknown provider: uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider”
3. Al probar con Jasmine código que usa el componente de Google Maps para AngularJS > “Unknown provider: uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider”
4. Al probar con Jasmine código que usa el componente de Google Maps para AngularJS “Unknown provider: uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider” se me comunica

Yo se que cada cual escribe el titulo de la pregunta como mejor pueda o crea, pero como ya mencione, pienso que de esta manera se hace más fácil de leer para toda la comunidad o esa es mi percepción, ustedes que opinan.

Comment: Tu pregunta es sobre citas en inglés, o citas en general? Por ejemplo, qué tal `"Archivo no encontrado" en XYZ programa`?  En ese caso también prefieres `Recibo en XYZ programa "Archivo no encontrado"`?

Comment: si el mensaje es en español pienso que de igual pero si fuera "file not found" en XYZ programa, se hace mas complicado aunque en este ejemplo no se vea, simplente coge una pregunta de las que puse y  lee alguno de los ejemplos para esa pregunta, ¿cual crees que es mas facil de leer y entender, hables o no ingles, si tu lengua es el español?

Comment: yo no es que lo prefiera por que es un antojo, solo pienso que es mas comodo para todos en los que me incluyo pero quizas me equivoco por eso lo publico aqui para ver que piensan, es mas que nada para intentar definir una estructura, algo asi como (pregunta)(mensaje en otro idioma), si estas acostumbrado a SO pues te da igual pero si eres un usuario nuevo que esta empezando y conoce SO.es por primera vez le sea lo mas facil posible.

Comment: espero explicarme bien y gracias por contestar

Comment: ¿Esto no es un duplicado de http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3/se-deber%C3%ADan-traducir-los-mensajes-de-error-que-forman-parte-de-las-preguntas ?

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista no, pues en esa pregunta se trata lo siguiente: ->Mi duda es, ¿deberíamos publicar estos mensajes de error tal cual se obtienen, o deberíamos publicarlos traducidos? (textualmente de la pregunta que usted menciona). Y yo propongo una estructura por ejemplo (pregunta)(mensaje en otro idioma sin traducir),por ejemplo. En ningún momento digo nada de traducir los mensajes de error o cualquier otro, es mas si te fijas digo ingles u otro idioma, espero explicarme bien y aclarar tu duda. gracias por contestar.

Comment: pues en SO original no tienen ese problema porque casi todos por no decir todos los mensajes son en ingles, su primer idioma y les da igual que el mensaje este antes de la pregunta o donde quiera, cosa que no ocurre en español, y creo que esto ayudaria a la comprension de la pregunta mas facilmente, puedes mirar los ejemplos y veras que la pregunta es casi exatamente igual a la original solo cambia el orden y quizas se añade alguna palabra para dar mas coherencia a  la pregunta gracias de nuevo por contestar

Comment: Yo no estoy de acuerdo. Si el texto en el título es un mensaje de error propio de un lenguaje x, es más relevante leer ese código de error que cualquier explicación en español. Y vuelvo a reiterar lo que ya he dicho en ocasiones anteriores, no es relevante en conocimiento de inglés respecto a los mensajes de error que lanza un lenguaje, ya que cualquiera que quiera programar en dicho lenguaje debe acostumbrarse a esos mensajes de error.

Answer (score 8):

Creo que **no** debe establecerse una regla como esa.

En mi opinión:

- No agrega una claridad "real" al título. Para alguien que no puede leer Inglés, será igual de confuso si la parte del título en este idioma está al inicio o al final de la pregunta.
- Al existir la regla, muchos usuarios novatos la violarían (y estoy seguro que muchos no novatos también). Reforzarla supondría un esfuerzo considerable para la comunidad (sobre todo para los moderadores) y creo que sería fuente de tensión o conflicto para quienes no le encuentren sentido a la regla.
- Un gran porcentaje del tráfico que reciban esas preguntas una vez respondidas vendrá de buscadores, en los cuales un porcentaje también importante incluyó precisamente dicho mensaje de error (o lo que fuera) como parte del criterio de búsqueda. Para estas personas, entre más pronto aparezca el mensaje en el título, mejor, pues confirmarán que el enlace les es útil y entrarán a él.