# Mejoremos los títulos de las preguntas que respondamos

Tags: discusión, preguntas, títulos-de-preguntas

Hace unos momentos estaba intentando ayudar a un usuario en la siguiente pregunta:

- [Como solucionar el error undefined reference to ... y id returned 1 exit status? c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194144/como-solucionar-el-error-undefined-reference-to-y-id-returned-1-exit-status)

A lo que sugerí un enlace del sitio en inglés, obvio que no es lo mejor pero para mí es lo más rápido y sencillo.

**¿y por qué para mi es lo más rápido y sencillo?**

Porque los títulos son muy descriptivos y simples:

- [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)

Un tiempo despues el usuario [@eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/463/eferion) válidamente me señala que hay un duplicado y es de esperar ya que es un problema clásico, el título original del post fue:

- [*¿cual es mi error?*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188610/cual-es-mi-error-implementaci%C3%B3n-de-templates) (yo la edité para intentar que sea más descriptivo).

Claramente el título es muy general y confuso, para mi punto de vista solo el OP y los usuarios que respondieron esa pregunta sabrían de qué se trata, otros usuarios como yo no le tomaríamos interés.

Asi que para mi el título es muy importante, nos resume el problema y nos da una idea rápida del tema que tratan las posibles soluciones. Así que nos deberíamoss esforzar en editarlos y mejorarlos, probablemente ese tipo de preguntas son de novatos que aunque les señales que lo mejoren no lo harán porque no entienden la importancia o no saben cómo hacerlo.

Así que mi propuesta es: **que los usuarios que respondamos tratemos de mejorarlas para hacerlas canónicas y señalarlas fácilmente como duplicados y así evitar duplicar esfuerzos sin sentido**.

¿Qué opiniones tienen al respecto? ¿Hay otras sugerencias?

Preguntas relacionadas:

- [Al preguntar o editar escribamos títulos de preguntas más concretos para que sea más fácil encontrarlas y clasificarlas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2936/al-preguntar-o-editar-escribamos-t%C3%ADtulos-de-preguntas-m%C3%A1s-concretos-para-que-sea)
- [Títulos de baja calidad en preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3574/t%C3%ADtulos-de-baja-calidad-en-preguntas)
- [Títulos de las preguntas que integran mensajes en ingles u otros idiomas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12/t%C3%ADtulos-de-las-preguntas-que-integran-mensajes-en-ingles-u-otros-idiomas)

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo. De hecho, me extraña que al escribir esta pregunta en Meta no te apareciera una con la misma idea: [Escribamos títulos de preguntas más concretos para que sea más fácil encontrarlas y clasificarlas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2936/83)

Comment: @fedorqui mi idea es que quienes respondamos mejoremos los títulos de las preguntas que justamente respondemos, muchas veces he visto excelentes respuestas en preguntas con malos títulos, y pues por ese segundo hecho muchas veces no son encontradas fácilmente :)

Comment: Ajá, comparto totalmente tu punto de vista. Yo intento hacerlo siempre que puedo y sé del tema y de hecho alguna vez se lo he comentado a [Paula](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paula-plus-plus) y eferion, que suelen hacer grandes ediciones al cuerpo de la pregunta pero sin tocar el título. Así que la idea sería: __si sabes del tema y entiendes qué se pregunta, modifica el título para que otra gente pueda encontrarlo más fácilmente__.

Comment: Sería ideal poner el texto del error, de ese modo las personas que estén teniendo el mismo problema, podrían encontrar la pregunta más fácilmente.

Comment: En el sitio ya existen preguntas relacionadas a esta, te sugiero revisar https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2936/escribamos-t%C3%ADtulos-de-preguntas-m%C3%A1s-concretos-para-que-sea-m%C3%A1s-f%C3%A1cil-encontrarla  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3574/t%C3%ADtulos-de-baja-calidad-en-preguntas https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12/t%C3%ADtulos-de-las-preguntas-que-integran-mensajes-en-ingles-u-otros-idiomas

Comment: @Jorgesys entiendo que existen preguntas relacionadas, una de ellas es la mia, pero esta pregunta tiene otro matiz, el objetivo de esta pregunta es exhortar a los que responden las preguntas en no solo fijarse en su respuesta(que es bastante) sino tambien en pulir la pregunta y especificamente el título, lo digo porque los usuarios que respondemos entendemos la ventaja de un título claro y conciso. :)

Comment: Sería bueno que mencionaras las preguntas de Meta más relevantes sobre la materia, en particular las que incluyen [meta-tag:títulos-de-preguntas]

Comment: @fedorqui Es que sin hacer mención a las preguntas en la materia parece un duplicado precisamente de la que refieres. En cualquier caso, es sólo una sugerencia, si el OP coincide contigo en que no es necesario, por mí no hay problema :)